# Making excel count logarithmically or by multiples of a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to generate a list of numbers that are multiples of 80 and I tried using =80*1, =80*2, etc for a few cells and filling the rest but it just repeats what I've already put in. Is there a command that can generate this list by counting logarithmically or a formula I can use to generate multiples of 80?

Comment: You could use "=row()*80".

Comment: @BillOertell -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just

=C5+80

is enough to get multiples of `80`, just ensure that the previous cell (`C5` in example)
is empty or `0`:

[image]

Or if you literally need to "Making excel count logarithmically",
you can use this formula:

```
=80*(EXP(LN(D6)-LN(80))+1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the top row is your first containing data, (i.e. there is no header row), then:

> =row()*80

will work. If your sheet does contain header row(s), then you'd want to use

> =(row()-1)*80

Substitute 1 for as many header rows as your sheet contains.

Answer (score 1):

the 500 can be changed to however many multiples you need.

> =MAKEARRAY(500, 1, LAMBDA(row_index, x, {row_index-1}*80))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a formula, you could put 80 in one cell, 160 in an adjacent cell, select the two cells, and drag the bottom right corner to make as many cells as you want in the pattern 80, 160, 240, 320, ….

If you already have a bunch of cells that have data in them, and you need to fill in an adjacent column, you can save yourself the dragging step.  Some number of clicks on the bottom right corner will make the 80, 160, 240, 320, … region extend down to match the bottom of the adjacent region that already has data.